# add white spaces between characters and special symbol in PHP

Tags: php

I am newbie of php, i want to know how to add whitespace between character and symbol or symbol and symbol, for example, the original string is “[PDF format(29.71MB)]“, how can i use function preg_replace or other method to represent the result as “[ PDF format (29.71MB) ]“?
i.e, I want to leave the space between symbol "[" and character "P" and also ")" and "]"

Many thanks

Simon

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you most as "accepted" at some point.

Answer (score 1):

For your string, regular expression looks a bit like too much to me:

```
$string = '[PDF format(29.71MB)]';
$string = str_replace(array('[', ']', '('), array('[ ', ' ]', ' ('), $string);
```

This replaces the chars that demand additional spaces with their variant with space.

Comment: This does not account for the space before the opening paren.

Comment: Did only read the "I want to leave to" sentence, right. -fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = "[PDF format(29.71MB)]";

$s = preg_replace("/[\[)](?!\s)/", "$0 ", $s);
$s = preg_replace("/(?!<\s)[\[(]/", " $0", $s);
$s = trim($s);

echo $s;
```

The two regular expressions

1. append a space to every `[` or `)` that is not already followed by a space
2. prepend a space to every `]` or `(` that is not already preceded by a space

See: http://ideone.com/No9dq

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "[PDF format(29.71MB)]";
$s = preg_replace("/([^\w.])/", " \\1 ", $s);
$s = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $s);
echo $s;
```

The first puts a space at each side of not a word character and not a dot. The second removes redundant whitespace.